# Keep getting Angular JS error not sure why

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am practicing Angularjs and made a simple module and controller. Im trying to display an elements data inside the controller on the HTML view page but the **{{student.name}}** only pops up. and im getting an error message saying:

> angular.js:15697 Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.2/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=MyController

Here is my js code:

```
var myApp= angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller=('MyController', function($scope){
    $scope.student={
        "name":"kevin",
        "age":"21",
        "school":"NYU"
    };
});
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <!-- angular -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MyController">
{{student.name}}
</body>
</html>
```

please help.

Comment: `myApp.controller` is a function. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller You try assigning a value to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have defined your controller is incorrect. You can do something like below:

```
angular.module('app').controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope){
     $scope.student={
       "name":"kevin",
       "age":"21",
       "school":"NYU"
     };
});
```

Sample working code here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-controllers-eauszw?file=app.js